# need to pass select tag option value to ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

*When i press the add button i need to get the value of select tag value*

**This is my ajax file**

```
function insertDep(){
   var ajaxRequest;
   try{
      ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }catch (e){
      try{
         ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      }catch (e) {

         try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }catch (e){
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
         }
      }
   }
   ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){   
      if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
         var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('addmegp');
         ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
      }
   }
   var unitnamedept = document.getElementById('unitnamedept').value;


   var queryString =  "?unitnamedept=" + unitnamedept;
   ajaxRequest.open("GET", "insertDept.php" + queryString, true);
   ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
```

**this is my html file**

```
<select> <option name="unitnamedept" id="unitnamedept" value="0" >--</option> <option value="D01">D01</option> <option value="D02">D02</option> <option value="D03">D03</option> <option value="D04">D04</option> </select>

<input type="button" name="ang" align="right" value="Add" onclick="insertDep()"/>
```

** i am having another page called insertDept.php**
*i use this page to display*

```
<?php
$unitnamedept = $_GET['unitnamedept'];
echo "$unitnamedept";
?>
```

### **when i pressed the button which receives only 0 value any help pls....**

Comment: You need to place **name and id attributes within select not in option**

Comment: This will help you.. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_select.asp

Comment: You can get the value using JavaScript. Here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript

Comment: @sreetharraja Do I need to post it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Use [:selected](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) Selector to get the value of the option - jQuery

Or

Use `e.options[e.selectedIndex].value` 

where `var e = document.getElementById('SelectID')` not the options

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="unitnamedept" id="unitnamedept"> <option  value="0" >--</option> <option value="D01">D01</option> <option value="D02">D02</option> <option value="D03">D03</option> <option value="D04">D04</option> </select>

<input type="button" name="ang" align="right" value="Add" onclick="insertDep()"/>
```

Change the id and  name attribute to select not to the option as i had given

Answer (score 0):

**Need to place name and id attributes within select not in option** @NarendraSisodia